# Angular 2 RC and ASP.NET Core JsonResult changes capitalisation of returned objects (using Observables)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, typescript, angular, observable

Both my C# Model and my Angular 2 RC objects have capitalised objects. However when returning the `JsonResult` the first capital letter of the property names for the objects changes to lowercase. There doesn't seem to be anywhere in my code where the uppercase should have changed to lowercase. Its confusing.

**Gender.cs**

```
public class Gender
{
    [Key]
    public short GenderId { get; set; }
    public string GenderName { get; set; }
}
```

**Gender.ts (View)**

```
export interface Gender {
    GenderId: number;
    GenderName: string;
}
```

The result is that my HTML has to use a lowercase first letter: `{{item.genderName}}` even though Intellisense uses `{{item.GenderName}}` and using what Intellisense, and what appears to be correct by code, prevents the results from being displayed..

**app.component.html**

```
<div style="position:relative">
<h1>Code First Database Migrations</h1>
<ul *ngFor="let item of items">
    <li>{{item.genderName}}</li>
</ul>
```

This is my `Controller`

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        var genders = _context.Genders;

        var query = from g in genders
                    select new { g.GenderId, g.GenderName };

        List<Gender> GenderList = new List<Gender>();

        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            Gender gender = new Gender();
            gender.GenderId = item.GenderId;
            gender.GenderName = item.GenderName;
            GenderList.Add(gender);

        }

        return Json(GenderList);
    }
```

This is my `DataService`:

**data.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Gender } from './gender';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
public collection$: Observable<Gender[]>;
private _collectionObserver: any;

constructor( @Inject(Http) private http: Http) {
    this.http = http;
    this.collection$ = new Observable(observer => {
        this._collectionObserver = observer;
    }).share();

}

getItems() {
    this.http.get('api/character').map((res: Response) => res.json()).subscribe(items => {
        this._collectionObserver.next(items);
        alert(JSON.stringify(items));
    });
}
```

}

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Inject, Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { Gender } from './gender';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    private items: Gender[];

    constructor( @Inject(DataService) public dataService: DataService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataService.collection$.subscribe(latestCollection => {
            this.items = latestCollection;
        });
        this.dataService.getItems();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but what's the question exactly?

Comment: Why is the uppercase changed to lowercase, its confusing and shouldn't happen as far as I am aware.

Comment: I believe that the problem is caused by ASP.NET MVC having `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` as the default `ContractResolver`. Find the config line and comment it out would solve your problem. However, as the consensus is to use PascalCase in back-end and camelCase in front-end, I'd strongly advise you to change your .ts model to camelCase :)

Comment: Thanks Harry for the advice, I'll follow convention. I've posted a fix as an answer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is covered in an announcement https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/194

To change from the convention modify `Startup.cs` `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services
    .AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
```